# background-image doesn't work with the pic in "img" folder only when online url

Tags: html, css, image, url, directory

I'm facing a weird issue here. My full screen background image **WORKS PERFECTLY WITH** online images url **BUT NOT WHEN**  it is located in the images folder (here named: img) and it has to be.

This site has an **"img" folder with bkg.png image inside**.

I've also put the image in the root folder just in case that would work with the following url(bkg.png); but it didn't work either. So finaly I've post the image on flickr and it is working. But **I need to understand the issue** and have it located in my img folder.

Thanks for your help.

Corinne.

```css
 /*into folder : root/css/mob_pss.css */
      
      * {
       margin: 0;
       padding; 0;
       font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
      }   

      *::after, *::before {
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      /*into folder : root/css/mob_bkg.css */
      
      html {
       /*I've tried those*/
        
       /*background-image: url(css/bkg.png);*/
       /*background-image: url(bkg.png);*/
        
       /*they didn't work*/
        
       /*but this works*/
       background-image: url(http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-14.jpg);
       background-position: center center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-size: cover;
       background-clip: border-box;
       background-color: #464646;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
       html {
         
       /*I've tried the following*/
         
       /*background-image: url(css/bkg.png);*/
       /*background-image: url(bkg.png);*/
         
       /*they didn't work*/
         
       /*but this works*/
         
       background-image:vb url(http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-14.jpg);

       }
      }
      body {
       background-color: transparent;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""> <!--language here-->

<head>
   <!--DEVICE MATTERS-->
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>FULL SCREEN BACKGROUND</title>
   <link href="css/mob_bkg.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/mob_pss.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <style></style>
</head>
<body>
<!---->  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "not working perfectly" mean? What is the expected behaviour? What is the actual behaviour? What have you done to debug it? Have you used the developer tools in your browser? Have you checked for errors on the console? Have you checked for errors in the Network tab?

Comment: Type `background-image: url(../img/bkg.png);` if your img folder next to css folder. Just locate your `img` folder correctly

Comment: It seems you are not able to located your image from the css file where it is used.

Comment: What are full paths to the .css file and .png files in your site?

Comment: @Deadpool .. the ../ solution WORKS PERFECT! what a relief.. it's going to shorten my code... I was about to tell you that IT WORKED WHEN I've put the SAME BLOCK OF CODE (with full path) INTO a SCRIPT TAG in MY HTML.. But that would have been heavy! (I still wonder why it doesn't work with the full path in my css though . But l'm good for now. THANKS again.

Comment: Thanks ... you just didnt know the file routing in case of js.

Answer (score 2):

consider below is your structure

```
index.html 
css 
-- style.css 
img 
-- pic1.jpg
```

if you write your css in `style.css` file

so I would write below code in `style.css`

```
body{
    background: url(../img/pic1.jpg);
}
```

`url()` in CSS is relative to the location of your css file

Comment: thank you the .../ solution works perfectly! Thank you !

Comment: Just read this Rahul... I just don't get the method to mark an answer as accepted!!! it's fustrating. I've even google it find some post on here and still didn't get by... Funny how people thinks that their ways of implementing options should be obvious (NOT!)... So actually that means that a whole lot of valuable answers are not marked as "ACCEPTED" just because of this (it's a shame and not productive). Maybe you can make it obvious to me ? (once you know, that's when ways can "eventually" become obvious... Right now I'm stucked with this simple issue to reward good answers... ARGHHH !

Comment: @CorinneSylvanise To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in., see [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the path for that images are all correct?

Answer (score -3):

try using single quotes,

```
   background-image: url('css/bkg.png');
   background-image: url('bkg.png');
```

Comment: What? Are you kidding? :)

Comment: @ Pragadeesh 

I've tried both, with and without the quotes


also regarding the path it is simple
since it's a the img folder in my root folder i've put it like that url(img/bkg.png) and also tried url('mg/bkg.png')

Comment: Ho ho ho .... a kiddo trying without testing. Dont use single quote. It will still work!

Comment: @ Deadpool and Pragadeesh

I am really dying to understand what's wrong
I mean the path is right to me all names are correct too : img - bkg.png
and I've put it like this :

img/bkg.png

what else could it be ?

Comment: funny though, the snippets was running ok when I've put it and now you can only see the background color - while it was working at first I didn't change it... I've also put it all in one piece in an html file (all css in a style tag) and it works fine... but still not with my pic in the folder I need it to be.

Comment: ok now the snippet here works fine again. Maybe a loading issue  when I've checked.

Comment: @Narek-T I see what you mean O.O

But : that's in my comment added for you guys at that moment, that's not what was and is in my file when testing. it is written as is:

background-image: url(img/bkg.png);

and both names are correct
but it STILL doesn't work...

I've spent a day on this  (I'm not kidding) must be something that I can't see (maybe a spelling issue but not that one) I've checked more than once, believe me.